# All files become owned by root in my Samba shared folder

Tags: linux, samba

I have a shared folder in samba (linux). The problem is that when I mount the shared folder, even in the same machine, all folders and files appears as owned by root, so I can only create or modify files using sudo.

All files and folders appears with permision 755.

The actual folder has permissions 777, is in the smbshare group
and is owned by sambauser.

I created the sambauser user as explained here: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-configure-samba-share-on-debian/ with this lines:

```
sudo useradd -M -s /sbin/nologin sambauser
sudo usermod -aG smbshare sambauser
```

This is my config file:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   follow symlinks = yes
   unix extensions = yes 
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S

[docs]
   comment = documents
   path = /home/myuser/Documents
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   force create mode = 775
   force directory mode = 775
   inherit permissions = yes
   valid users = @smbshare
```

My command for mounting is:

```
sudo mount.smb3 //localhost/docs ~/m -o user=sambauser
```

I also tried:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -ouser=sambauser,vers=3.0 //localhost/docs m
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I just solved the problem with the optin uid=myuser in the mount command. But I don't understand the meaning of that. Also in the mount.smb3 help it says that option is not needed in cifs supporting unix extensions.

Comment: Now I can create files but they become owned by 'nobody'